# Referencing a particular cell and on the next pass reference the cell below

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a project and been playing around with VBA to reference a table of data and build Sheets with this info.
I can't put the real thing on here but I've built a variation with safe data in.

Basically my script works fine how I need it to, now I'm just keen to improve my knowledge a bit more on error checking as usually I just find the error and fix it. These 2 I have though i feel there is a more elegant way and I'm hoping someone here can help.

So the script references col C in a table, and creates new Sheets for it and renames them to the data found in the column.

At the end of the script I get a 1004 error, I know this is because the script got through all the data in the column and has nothing else to add. Is there a way to stop it sending up this error message please?

Also if I paritally ran the script, and got a couple of Sheets created. When I re-run it I get errors, as the Sheets are already made. Is there a way of telling the script that if it tries to name a Sheet with something that already exists then ignore it and move onto the next one?

I've uploaded a copy of the Excel sheet with the relevant code I'm on about along with some screenshots of each error.
I'll also post the code below after the sign-off.

Thanks in advance,

AM

```
Sub Addsheet()

Dim Row As Integer
Dim ColC As Integer
Dim i As Long


Row = 2
ColC = Worksheets("Member Data").Cells(Worksheets("Member Data").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To ColC

Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = Worksheets("Member Data").Cells(Row, "C").Value
Row = Row + 1

Next i


End Sub
```

[Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orkWx.png)

[Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7AHA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense to use an `For i` loop and then use another variable to increment `Row = Row + 1`, because `i` automatically increments on `Next i`. So just use that `i` if it is already there.

Another point is that you should use `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. Also there is no benefit in using `Integer` at all in VBA, therefore we can recommend always to use `Long` instead of `Integer`.

For checking if a worksheet already exists I recommend to write a function (so we can re-use that code later if we need to).

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Addsheet()
    Dim LastRowC As Long 'use Long Excel has more rows than Integer can handle    
    LastRowC = Worksheets("Member Data").Cells(Worksheets("Member Data").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long        
    For i = 2 To LastRowC 'loop from row 2 to last used row
        Dim wsName As String
        wsName = Worksheets("Member Data").Cells(i, "C").Value
        'make sure the wsName cannot exceed 31 characters and doesn't include
        'invalid characters for sheet names, or include an error handling here.

        If WorksheetExists(wsName) = False Then 'call our function to check if sheet name already exists
            Sheets.Add.Name = wsName 'add and rename the sheet
        End If
    Next i 'increment i+1 and do next loop
End Sub

Private Function WorksheetExists(wsName As String) As Boolean
    WorksheetExists = False 'default
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count 'loop through all worksheets
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name = wsName Then 'check if name exists
            WorksheetExists = True 'let the function return that it exists
            Exit For 'we can stop searching when name was found
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Probably should have mentioned in the OP that when I said "playing around with VBA"   I should have said "opened up this VBA thing on Mon and this is what I've managed to work out by myself so far"     I'm totally new to this stuff, so as to if things make sense then sure they probably don't, all I know is this order and wording is doing what I need now and I'm just hoping to sort the errors out.  Thanks for the code, it will take me a long time to reverse engineer, as I'm just learning this stuff, but I'll go through and see if I can apply to what I have already.  Cheers

Comment: @tigrepojke Nothing wrong with that everyone has to start somewhere. I tried to explain the essential points, so feel free to ask if it is unclear what I did.

Comment: Thanks I will, but first I'll use your code example to have a go myself so I'm not wasting anyone's time. And also I learn better ;)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, loop through the sheets and check if one with the name exists like:

```
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "MySheet" Then
        exists = True
    End If
Next i

If Not exists Then
    Worksheets.Add.Name = "MySheet"
End If
```

Also, instead of using i as your counter, why not use `Row`, and remove the `Row = Row + 1` This I believe should solve your first question.

Comment: Cheers, appreciate it. I'll look through and see if I can manipulate that into my code. Forgot to mention I'm new to this VBA starting this week, so I've no idea why I'd use Rows over Longs over Integers etc.....but I do appreciate the time and look forward to playing around some more with it.c

Comment: No problem, the answer below mine is a complete one so you may want to mark that as the answer.

Comment: Cheers bud, your code was good also. If I wasn't so new I'd upvote it, one of these days that magic 15 number will be reached.